# multi-array slice including sub arrays

Tags: php, arrays, slice

I have found many post related to array_slice, but none re: a nested array that mirrors this.  I have an array:

```
array (
Key1 => values,
Key2 => array[0] => 
        Keys => values,
Key3 => array[0]=> 
        Keys => values,
Key4 => array[0]  // Key = LineItems
    Key => array[0]
    keys => values,
        Key => array[0]
            Keys => values,
            Key => array[0]
                Keys => values,
    Key => array[1]
    Keys => Values
        Key => array[0]
            Keys => values,
            Key => array[0]
                Keys => values,
                Key => array[0]
                    Keys => values,             
Key5 => array[0]  // Key = AddressRepository
        keys =>values,
    )
```

I need to slice it and return this:

```
Key4 => array[0]
    Key => array[0]
    keys => values,
        Key => array[0]
            Keys => values,
            Key => array[0]
                Keys => values,
    Key => array[1]
    Keys => Values
        Key => array[0]
            Keys => values,
            Key => array[0]
                Keys => values,
                Key => array[0]
                    Keys => values,
```

I am able to return array[4][0][0] and [4][1][0] using this function (I'm using key names for array[4] and array[5] since it's associative) but not the sub-arrays:

```
function sliceLineItems($array) {
    $start = array_search('LineItems', array_keys($array));
    echo $start;flush();
    $end = (array_search('AddressRepository', $array)-1);        
    $slicedLineItems = array_slice($array, $start, $end, true);
    return $slicedLineItems;
}
```

I need all of the sub-arrays in Key4.

Comment: Just try `$arr['key4']`

Comment: DOH.. talk about trying to over complicate something!  That works - thank you!

Comment: DIY first understand the array